# Immediate write of @ifnextchar

Tags: macros, errors

While writing a test for **l3build** I ran across a problem on outputting the result of a command that used `@ifnextchar`. Concretely, `\TYPE{\command}` gave a compiling error. I have reduced it to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\lookahead{\@ifnextchar{z}{hello}{goodbye}}
\immediate\write128{\lookahead z}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

On my machine (pdflatex, TeX Live 2020/Debian) the previous code gives the error: `Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }`. I am somewhat out of my depth here, so after some searching I decided it would be best to ask for help. Do you know why it gives this mistake and could one do anything to solve it? Note that the output method shouldn't be changed, since it is essentially the one used by **l3build**.

Many thanks!

Comment: It won't work. `\@ifnextchar` is not expandable, so it won't work in `\write`. What exactly is your application for `\@ifnextchar`here? Maybe it's possible to change to an expandable approach

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand` makes your command robust via the latex `\protect` mechanism but that has no effect on `\write` you would need to use  `\protected@write` however that would just make it write  `\lookahead z`  not `hello`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I am afraid the use of `@ifnextchar` is difficult to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer an expandable mechanism `\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` by means of which you can have LaTeX check by means of macros that process delimited arguments whether a macro argument's leading tokens form a specific set of tokens.

`\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` is different from `\@ifnextchar`/`\kernel@ifnextchar` in several aspects:

- `\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` is expandable.
- `\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` does not "look ahead" at the next token in the token-stream. Instead it does "look" at the first tokens of a macro-argument.

(Both with `\@ifnextchar`/`\kernel@ifnextchar` and with `\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` you may need to pay attention when `\uppercase`/`\lowercase`/`\MakeUppercase`/`\MakeLowercase` and the like play a rôle.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
%==========[code for checking leading token-sequences in arguments]============
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Exchange two arguments. (From each argument an outermost level of 
%% surrounding braces will be removed if present.)
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific 
%% token-sequence that does not contain explicit character tokens of 
%% category code 1 or 2:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<a <token sequence> without explicit 
%%                                character tokens of category code
%%                                1 or 2>}%
%%                              {a <single non-space token> that does 
%%                                _not_ occur in <token sequence> >}%
%%                              {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case
%%                                <argument which is to be checked> has
%%                                <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case 
%%                                <argument which is to be checked>
%%                                does not have <token sequence> as
%%                                leading tokens>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[4]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{ }\expandafter\@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
   \UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens#4#3#1#2}{}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\@secondoftwo}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter}\expandafter\@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<token sequence>}%
%% Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
%% until reaching <token sequence>-sequence and spit that out
%% nested in braces.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\long\def#1##1#2{{##1}}}%
}%
%=======[end of code for checking leading token-sequences in arguments]=========

\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\zcheck}{z}%
\newcommand\lookahead[1]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{z}{.}{\zcheck}{hello}{goodbye} #1%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\immediate\write128{ble ble \lookahead{y bla} blu blu}

\immediate\write128{ble ble \lookahead{{z} bla} blu blu}

\immediate\write128{ble ble \lookahead{z bla} blu blu}

\end{document}
```

With the example above I get this on the terminal:

```
ble ble goodbye y bla blu blu
ble ble goodbye {z} bla blu blu
ble ble hello z bla blu blu
```

Another approach could be having `\lookahead` perform a brace-hack for removing the opening-brace before calling another macro `\lookaheadb` for actually performing the lookahead via `\@ifnextchar` and having `\@ifnextchar` perform another brace-hack for adding an opening-brace and calling `\immediate\write` on the argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\lookahead{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\lookaheadb\expandafter\@gobble\string
}%
\newcommand\lookaheadb{%
  \@ifnextchar{z}%
  {\immediate\write128\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\@gobble\string}hello }%
  {\immediate\write128\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\@gobble\string}goodbye }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lookahead{y bla bla bla}

\lookahead{{z} bla bla bla}

\lookahead{z bla bla bla}

\end{document}
```

With the example above I get this on the terminal:

```
goodbye y bla bla bla
goodbye {z} bla bla bla
hello z bla bla bla
```

With this approach `\lookahead` cannot be nested inside the `\write` command but is calling the `\write`-command.